# For what n,m the following conditon hold

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose their are n people and each person is friend with exactly m other people . What should be the relation between n and m  for the following condition to hold and how to prove that .

For example - for m = 3 i.e a person can be friends with exactly 3 other people 
i think n should be multiple of four . I visualized it by considering group of people as corners of square and lines between them denoting friendship .

Comment: What "following condition"??

Answer (score 1):

You are considering a graph with $n$ vertices, where each vertex has degree $m$. That is, you are considering a graph with a length $n$ degree sequence $(m,m,\cdots,m)$. I am assuming that a person cannot be friends with themselves, they cannot be 'twice' friends with another, and all friendships are reciprocal. Then you are considering undirected graphs without loops or multi-edges, i.e. simple graphs. Then consider the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) which tells you that a choice of $(n,m)$ works if and only if $nm$ is even, and
$$\sum_{i=1}^k d_i \leq k(k-1) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n \min(d_i,k),$$
for each $k$ in $1\leq k\leq n$. But for $k\leq m$ this is just
$$km\leq k(k-1)+k(n-k)$$
and for $m<k$ this is just
$$km\leq k(k-1)+ m(n-k).$$

For $k\leq m$ this just says $m\leq (k-1)+(n-k)= n-1$ and for $m<k$ it says:
$$km\leq k^2-k+mn-mk\implies m\leq \frac{k(k-1)}{2k-n}.$$

Additionally, we know that $nm$ is even, and thus one of $n$ and $m$ must be even (or both).

Also, using the [Havel-Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) we can construct such a graph for $n=6$ and $m=3$ (contradicting your $4|n$ claim):

[image: Simple graph with six nodes, all of degree 3]

( [I plotted that using this website](https://graphonline.ru/en/) )

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking: for which integers $n\ge1$ and $m\ge0$ does there exist an $m$-regular graph of order $n$, that is, a graph on $n$ vertices in which each vertex has degree $m$?

The obvious necessary conditions are that $n\gt m$ and $mn$ is even. These conditions are also sufficient. Let the vertices be $n$ equally spaced points on a circle. If $m\lt n$ and $m$ is even, join each vertex to the $\frac m2$ nearest vertices on either side. If $m\lt n$ and $m$ is odd and $n$ is even, join each vertex to the diametrically opposite vertex and to the $\frac{m-1}2$ nearest vertices on either side.

There are two $2$-regular graphs of order $6$, namely, the cycle graph $C_6$ and the graph $C_3+C_3$ consisting of two disjoint triangles. The complement of either of those graphs will be a $3$-regular graph of order $6$. The complement of $C_6$ is the graph shown in Alex Clark's answer; the complement of $C_3+C_3$ is the complete bipartite graph $K_{3,3}$.